Dspy for multiple outputs
I am trying to extract some entities from email through dspy. I am stuck at the validation metric, Can anyone guide me how to create a function for that where I can verify multiple outputs?
I tried using the exact match functions but they are only for single output field of Answer

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

https://dspy-docs.vercel.app/docs/building-blocks/typed_predictors
You can use pydantic model for input/output formats and then use dspy.InputField() and dspy.OutputField() to accomodate multiple outputs. Hope this starts you off in the right direction.

You can implement it like this:
class Routing(dspy.Signature):
"""some short description of the task here""
input_query = dspy.InputField()
output_field_1: List[str] = dspy.InputField(desc="description here " format = list)
output_field_2: str = dspy.InputField(desc="description here 2 ")

